# Angular2 Form Validation with regular expression

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Is there a good way to bind a regular expression to an input field and only if the expressions is matched, the submit button can be clicked?

Im looking for an smooth system like the ngModel 2-way-binding or does it requiere alot work?

Below an code example, with my regular expression, but it doesnt work like i wish too

```
<span class="input-group-addon">Code</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="voucherCode" [(ngModel)]="tempPromotion['response_payload']['promotionCode']"
  name="voucherCode" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+">
```

**EDIT:**

Some more Code to look at

**tempPromotion**

```
{
    "status": {
        "statusCode": "0",
        "statusMessage": "OK"
    },
    "response_payload": {
        "id": "1",
        "promotionCode": "A1239.ESR_ESW",
        "active": true,
        "ruleset_list": [{
            "id": "83",
            "condition": "saleschannel.totalamount > `15` && current_datetime < `2017-08-30T15:50.01`",
            "results": [{
                    "id": "110",
                    "value_path": "saleschannel.totalamount",
                    "expression": "mul(#VALUE, 0.9)",
                    "valid": false
                },
                {
                    "id": "186",
                    "value_path": "saleschannel.totalamount",
                    "expression": "sendTeaser(\"{\"a\": 1}\")",
                    "valid": false
                }
            ],
            "active": true
        }],
        "saleschannel_list": [{
                "id": "2",
                "name": "A",
                "trackingId": "3",
                "public": false
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "B",
                "public": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**voucher.html**

```
<div id="top" *ngIf="tempPromotion" class="voucher-edit">
  <form onsubmit="" #VoucherForm="ngForm">


    <div class="input-group">   <!-- Always one input Field -->
            <span class="input-group-addon">Code</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="voucherCode" [(ngModel)]="tempPromotion['response_payload']['promotionCode']" name="voucherCode">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></span>
    </div>

    <div class="card" *ngFor="let rule of tempPromotion['response_payload']['ruleset_list']; let i = index"> <!-- NGFOR -->
        <strong style="margin-left: 5px">Regelwerk</strong>
        <small>{{rule['id']}}</small>

    <div class="input-group"> <!-- Atleast one field, can be infinit -->
        <span class="input-group-addon">Bedingung</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rule{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="rule['condition']" name="rule{{i}}">
    </div>


    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Pfad</th>
                <th>Ergebnis</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let result of rule['results']; let x = index"> <!-- NGFOR -->
                <td>{{result['id']}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="valuePath{{i}}{{x}}" [(ngModel)]="result['value_path']" name="valuePath{{i}}{{x}}"></td> <!-- Atleast one field, can be infinit -->
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount{{i}}{{x}}" [(ngModel)]="result['expression']" name="discount{{i}}{{x}}"></td> <!-- Atleast one field, can be infinit -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-success" (click)="EditVar = 0; ; voucherService.putVoucher(addOverride(this.tempPromotion['response_payload']));"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Speichern</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-md btn-warning" (click)="EditVar = 0; resetData();"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Zurücksetzten</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What does **it doesnt work like i wish too** mean exactly?

Comment: @AJT_82 if the input is not Valid it shows the .css, but i still cant hit the submit button.

Comment: Well from my understanding you don't want the button to be clickable unless the field is valid? This I gather from this line: *"and only if the expressions is matched, the submit button can be clicked"* So what is that you really want? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 you just wrote what i want to achieve, at the moment i can give the input field an string and it will be checked an this works as it should, but im not able to link this to the submit button. Basiclly i need something like an `if` on the submit button but i dont know how to get the valid true or false from the pattern check

Comment: `voucherCode.errors?.pattern` is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @AJT_82 what does it return, the error code or an true/false? If the last one it might be the one i looking for

Comment: it returns true if it does not match, false if it matches. It doesn't really matter which way though :) If you want to disable button you can do: `[disabled]="voucherCode.errors?.pattern"`

Comment: @AJT_82 Lovely, do you have an Idea how to use this way with more than one input field to validate? I have like 5 static and 2 in an *ngFor loop so i dont know how long that would be, depends on the JSON i get from the API.

Comment: @AJT_82 , well i tryed to get the plunker working but im not able sadly, never used plunker before. I will just Upload the ´.html´ and the ´.json´. Hope this is okay too

Comment: @AJT_82 I deleted unecessary parts of the code for this question, im sry. Is it better now? My Problem is that i want to use `pattern="regexp"` but i dont know how i make my Form react to invalid inputs, so that i cant "submit" the form

Comment: here's a plunker, there is still some code missing from your part. So it's not completely working. http://plnkr.co/edit/TfSjbJedY5YZnZ0F38SP?p=preview And you have nowhere any "pattern" in your form, so I don't really know what you want to do here, and how form should *react* as you say it. It's just to set the validations you want and disable the submit button based on those validations, or more general like JGFMK answered to just disable button if form is not valid.

Comment: @AJT_82 Since Yesterday im trying to figure out why your plunker doesnt work besides the field `tempPromotion['response_payload']['promotionCode']`. Its pretty much the same code as on my project. Anyway you can add the following pattern to the only working field `pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+"`. So I want to achieve, if the input on thie field match the pattern submit should be enabled, otherwhise it should be disabled.

Comment: Finally starting to get the point here. I'd suggest you switch to a reactive form, which gives you more control. In this case you could create a custom validator for checking the pattern on each field and then disable/enable submit button based on that.

Comment: @AJT_82 Damn, i hoped i dont need to rewrite my whole Form... was a lot of work for me :/ Do you have any links for reactive Form which might help me to understand what a reactive Form is and how to use it?

Comment: Well, you don't **have** to change to reactive form, but if I was you, I would do that ;) You have so much better control over the form. You **can** use a custom validator for template driven form. I have never done it myself, but maybe this will help if you want to stay on the route of template driven form ? https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-template-driven-form-validators/

Comment: @AJT_82 You are awesome, if i have any questions again i will tag you in the comment section again

Comment: Sure thing, do that! Good luck with the custom validator! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 quick question on my `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="voucherCode" [(ngModel)]="tempPromotion['response_payload']['promotionCode']"
  name="voucherCode" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+">` i added `[class.sucess]="xxx"`, what do i have to change with the `xxx` so the .css class is added if the pattern is matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#simple-template-driven-forms):

```
<form #heroForm="ngForm"  *ngIf="active"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
             [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And they talk about Regular Expressions later [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validation). It involves creating a directive that you can use to do the kind of thing you asked for.